# Trouble with winros installation

Tags: ros, windows, catkin, winros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,

I'm trying to install winros on Windows 7 (64 Bit) and have some trouble with the step "winros sdk configure" like described in http://www.ros.org/wiki/win_ros/Msvc%20Build%20Environment%20-%20Fuerte.
This is my console output:

```
"Configuring the build"

-- +++ catkin
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: C:/work/build_sdk/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: C:/work/build_sdk;C:/work/build_sdk/cmake
CMake Warning at catkin/cmake/test/gtest.cmake:99 (message):
  gtest not found, C++ tests can not be built.  You can run 'svn checkout
  http://googletest.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release-1.6.0 gtest' in the root
  of your workspace
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  catkin/cmake/all.cmake:133 (include)
  catkin/CMakeLists.txt:8 (include)


-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: C:/work/build_sdk/test_results
-- catkin 0.5.65
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 32 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - ros_comm (metapackage)
-- ~~  - rosconsole
-- ~~  - rosgraph
-- ~~  - rosgraph_msgs
-- ~~  - roslaunch
-- ~~  - rosmaster
-- ~~  - rosmsg
-- ~~  - rospack
-- ~~  - rosparam
-- ~~  - rospy
-- ~~  - rosservice
-- ~~  - rostest
-- ~~  - std_srvs
-- ~~  - test_roslib_comm
-- ~~  - xmlrpcpp
-- ~~  - roscpp
-- ~~  - rosout
-- ~~  - actionlib
-- ~~  - message_filters
-- ~~  - rosnode
-- ~~  - rostopic
-- ~~  - roswtf
-- ~~  - test_roscpp
-- ~~  - test_rosgraph
-- ~~  - test_roslaunch
-- ~~  - test_rosmaster
-- ~~  - test_rosparam
-- ~~  - test_rospy
-- ~~  - test_rosservice
-- ~~  - topic_tools
-- ~~  - rosbag
-- ~~  - test_rosbag
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'ros_comm'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ros_comm/ros_comm)
CMake Error at ros_comm/ros_comm/CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package):
  Could not find module Findcatkin.cmake or a configuration file for package
  catkin.

  Adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to find Findcatkin.cmake or set catkin_DIR to the
  directory containing a CMake configuration file for catkin.  The file will
  have one of the following names:

    catkinConfig.cmake
    catkin-config.cmake



-- +++ processing catkin package: 'rosconsole'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(ros_comm/tools/rosconsole)
CMake Error at ros_comm/tools/rosconsole/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package):
  Could not find module Findcatkin.cmake or a configuration file for package
  catkin.

  Adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to find Findcatkin.cmake or set catkin_DIR to the
  directory containing a CMake configuration file for catkin.  The file will
  have one of the following names:

    catkinConfig.cmake
    catkin-config.cmake



CMake Error at ros_comm/tools/rosconsole/CMakeLists.txt:12 (message):
  Couldn't find log4cxx library


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

"You may now proceed with 'winros sdk build'"
```

The Problem is that there is only a "catkinConfig.cmake" in directory C:\work\build_sdk\catkin\catkin_generated\installspace but I'm guessing that this is not the right one because that file will be created by the build process which is started with "winros sdk configure". The advise to adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to find Findcatkin.cmake is also not working for me because there exists no Findcatkin.cmake.

Has somebody experience with that problem?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61016/trouble-with-winros-installation/) by [ChrisEule](https://answers.ros.org/users/2782/chriseule/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Glad to see you got it working.

The navigation stack won't work out of the box - it's got a few dependencies we haven't ported yet (porting is a bit painful, not only the usual cross platform bugs, but each package needs to implement all of the windows declspec macros).

It's not too hard and I'm looking forward to the day people start porting some of the ros stacks themselves (some early notes [here](http://ros.org/wiki/win_ros/Contributing)), but for now, the winros builds are primarily intended as a way to link your linux robot to the windows world, or a windows based driver.

Ubuntu virtual machine sounds like the way to go for you.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2013-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChrisEule](https://answers.ros.org/users/2782/chriseule/) on 2013-05-07**:
Thank you very much for your quick reply. I think I will go back to Ubuntu

**Comment by [ChrisEule](https://answers.ros.org/users/2782/chriseule/) on 2013-05-14**:
@Daniel How do you appraise the work to port a stack like the navigation? Isn't it very hard and lots of work because of all the package dependencies?

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2013-05-19**:
It will still be easier and better running a 'linux ros robot' for many reasons. Because of this we're generally avoiding robot stacks and just working on those which will let you link and work with a 'linux ros robot'. e.g. rqt, tf etc.